# f.write keeps returning "NameError: name 'productre_time' is not defined"

Tags: python, csv, file, exception, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab information using beautiful soup and write the data in a csv file. The code works well so far but when I add the f.write I keep getting the NameError. I tried renaming the variables and played around with the indents but I still can't fix the problem. What am I doing wrong? (if I can fix this issue, this will be my first program so bear with me)

Here's my code;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/property'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "container--2uFyv"})
container = containers[0]


filename = "tonaton_data.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "product_name, upload_time, bednbath, product_location, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    try:
        product_name = container.select_one("div div:nth-of-type(2)").span.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(product_name)

    try:
        bednbath = container.select_one("div div:nth-of-type(2)").div.div.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(bednbath)

    try:
        location_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "description--2-ez3"})
        product_location = location_container[0].text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(product_location)

    try:
        price_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "price--3SnqI color--t0tGX"})
        product_price = price_container[0].span.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(product_price)

    try:
        date_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "updated-time--1DbCk"})
        productre_time = date_container[0].text
    except IndexError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(productre_time)

    f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + bednbath + "," + product_location + "," + product_price + "," + productre_time + "\n")

f.close()
```

Error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mmu/PycharmProjects/RealEstate Project/Pofore_tonaton.py", line 59, in <module>
    f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + bednbath + "," + product_location + "," + product_price + "," + productre_time + "\n")
NameError: name 'productre_time' is not defined
```

Comment: can you post the whole error? @KeyserPython

Comment: Look carefully at the error message, and then at the code. Clearly, the error is complaining about `productre_time` not getting defined. Where do you expect the value of `productre_time` to come from? It comes from `productre_time = date_container[0].text`, yes? Okay, now I see that you have considered the possibility that an `IndexError` is raised by that `[0]`. *If that happens*, what do you expect to happen to the name `productre_time`? Do you expect it to become defined anyway? Why? With what value?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want `product_time` to print 0 or blank if there is an `IndexError`. Only the first two products don't have the `productre_time` class but I want to print something there anyway so that the script runs without an issue

Comment: Pay more attention to what I wrote. When the `IndexError` occurs, what did you think the code *will actually do*? Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel when the `IndexError` occurs, I expect the script to `print(0)` because of the exception

Comment: Yes; but what do you think will happen to `productre_time`? Do you think a value will be assigned to it? What value? How?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think `productre_time` will give me 0 if there is an `IndexError` or its text value if there is a text.  I think it will print 0 because I have the exception `except IndexError: print(0)`

Comment: Why do you expect doing `print(0)` to cause `productre_time` to become equal to 0?

Comment: No, I am dead serious. **You need to think more clearly about how the code works.** To learn programming effectively you must be able to answer precise questions about what is going on, pay attention etc. `print(0)` does or says nothing about `productre_time`, therefore it does not cause `productre_time` to have a value. If it didn't already have a value, it still doesn't. Your code unconditionally attempts to format a string with `productre_time` in it. This is not possible unless a value has already been given.

Comment: Okay. In the code, `productre_time` has been assigned a value, `productre_time = date_container[0].text`

Answer (score 0):

Problem you were facing is if you couldn't retrieve a value from soup object, then that variable will not be initialized. Hence, you have initialize all the variables with empty string before

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/property'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "container--2uFyv"})
container = containers[0]


filename = "tonaton_data.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "product_name, upload_time, bednbath, product_location, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    try:
        product_name = ""
        product_name = container.select_one("div div:nth-of-type(2)").span.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(product_name)

    try:
        bednbath = ""
        bednbath = container.select_one("div div:nth-of-type(2)").div.div.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(bednbath)

    try:
        product_location = ""
        location_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "description--2-ez3"})
        product_location = location_container[0].text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(product_location)

    try:
        product_price = ""
        price_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "price--3SnqI color--t0tGX"})
        product_price = price_container[0].span.text
    except AttributeError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(product_price)

    try:
        productre_time = ""
        date_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "updated-time--1DbCk"})
        productre_time = date_container[0].text
    except IndexError:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(productre_time)

    f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + bednbath + "," + product_location + "," + product_price + "," + productre_time + "\n")

f.close()
```

Output:

```
1yr very nice 2bedrooms flat for rent@West Hills Mall
Beds: 2, Baths: 2
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 650 /month
0
Land for sale at East Legon Hills
100/70 acre
Accra, Land
GH₵ 100,000
0
Locomotive new 2bedrm spintex
Beds: 2, Baths: 1
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 1,200 /month
1 minute
For sale,9bedrooms house @East Legon
Beds: 9, Baths: 10
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 8,820,000
1 minute
AN EXECUTIVE NEWLY BUILT CHAMBER AND HALL FOR@SPINTEX
Beds: 2, Baths: 2
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 800 /month
2 minutes
AN EXECUTIVE NEWLY BUILT 2BEDROOM 2WASHROOM FOR RENT@SPINTEX
Beds: 2, Baths: 2
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 1,000 /month
2 minutes
AN EXECUTIVE CHAMBER AND HALL APARTMENT FOR@SPINTEX
Beds: 2, Baths: 1
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 500 /month
3 minutes
REGISTERED 5 BRM HOUSE AT KOKROKO MALLAM
Beds: 5, Baths: 3
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 400,000
4 minutes
SHOP WITH WASHROOM AT ARKO ADJEI PARK, OSU
15 x 15 sqft
Accra, Commercial Property
GH₵ 1,000 /month
7 minutes
Sophisticated new 3bedrm HOUSE spintex
Beds: 3, Baths: 4
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 2,000 /month
7 minutes
NEW & EXECUTIVE 2 MASTER BEDROOM APARTMENT NEAR MAINROAD, TETEGU
Beds: 2, Baths: 3
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 1,800 /month
7 minutes
nice ordinary single room at Agege 205

Accra, Rooms
GH₵ 100 /month
23 minutes
executive 4bed house for sale at kasoa cp
Beds: 4, Baths: 3
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 280,000
26 minutes
nice 3bed self compound @south odorko
Beds: 3, Baths: 2
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 1,300 /month
31 minutes
2bedroom At Abelemkpe. 1year
Beds: 2, Baths: 1
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 700 /month
34 minutes
5 Bedroom house for rent BOTWE
Beds: 4, Baths: 6
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 12,000 /month
39 minutes
Three bedrooms self compound house for sale at Odorkor
Beds: 3, Baths: 3
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 1,540,000
1 hour
Genuine Lands with land Title/land Deeds
100 acre
Greater Accra, Land
GH₵ 25,000
1 hour
4 bedroom self compound for rent in north dzorwulu
Beds: 4, Baths: 4
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 3,000 /month
1 hour
2 Bedrooms & A Hall For Rent Ntankoful
Beds: 2, Baths: 1
Sekondi Takoradi, Apartments
GH₵ 450 /month
1 hour
2 bedroom apartment for rent at Tse Addo Teshie Manet
Beds: 2, Baths: 3
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 2,000 /month
1 hour
2 bedroom apartments at Madina Adenta Oyarifa
Beds: 2, Baths: 2
Accra, Apartments
GH₵ 1,300 /month
1 hour
Airport 5 Bedrooms Mansion For Rent
Beds: 5, Baths: 5
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 18,560 /month
1 hour
East Legon 4 Bedrooms House With Swiming Pool For Sale
Beds: 4, Baths: 4
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 3,770,000
1 hour
Airport 5 Bedrooms House With Swiming Pool
Beds: 5, Baths: 5
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 29,000 /month
1 hour
Newly executive 3bedroom self contain for sale at oyarifa Ghana flag
Beds: 3, Baths: 2
Greater Accra, Houses
GH₵ 350,000
1 hour
3bedroom house 4sale @Adenta
Beds: 3, Baths: 4
Accra, Houses
GH₵ 650,000
1 hour
```

Comment: I run your code and got this error;   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/m/PycharmProjects/RealEstate Project/Extra.py", line 62, in <module>
    f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + bednbath + "," + product_location + "," + product_price + "," + productre_time + "\n")
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b5' in position 74: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Can you give the url for which this is happening?

Comment: Are you running in python2 or python3?

Comment: Run the script in python 3

Comment: I am running the script in python 3.8.3

Comment: I'm also running the same, it's working fine in my system

Comment: I guess the problem is from my end then

Comment: May be. Anyway if you feel this has answered your question, upvote and accept the answer